# Combine separate queries in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

I have two search terms "86746184549" and "3302093809". I am executing two separate term queries to fetch one document matching each of the ids.

```
"size":1,
"query":{
  "term":{
    "from_user_id": "86746184549"
  }

}
```

and

```
"size":1,
"query":{
  "term":{
    "from_user_id": "3302093809"
  }

}
```

Is there are a way to combine these 2 queries, something similar to what we do in facets.

```
 {
    "facets":{
      "facet_1":{

       },
      "facet_2":{

       },
      "facet_3":{

       }  
    }
 }
```

I don't think the [terms query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query.html) will work here because, that wont return documents containing distinct `from_user_id` field.

The reason I want to combine the queries is because, say if I have 100 such terms then I will be making 100 calls!! to the elasticsearch server.

Comment: I think terms query is exactly what you need. Why do you think it will not work for you? I am not sure I understand what you mean by "distinct from_user_id field".

Comment: I tried doing `{"size":2,"query":{"terms":{"from_user_id": ["86746184549","333621309995644"]}}}, but this gave me 2 results containing the same `from_user_id` value -> "86746184549". How do I fetch 2 records that contain the 2 distinct `from_user_id` values. I don't want to query the entire data set that's the reason why I have specified `size` in the request body. Just want to fetch 2 records one containing "86746184549" and the other "333621309995644" in the `from_user_id` field.
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [Field Collapsing/Combining](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/256), which is highly sought-after feature of elasticsearch that's not implemented yet. Meanwhile, you can use [Multi Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-search.html) to combine several term requests into one.

Comment: looking forward to this new feature!